# Rails 4 not recursively sourcing lib/assets directory or application_lib.js manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pipeline, assets

$ rails --version
Rails 4.0.1

I want to be able to have a separate manifest file, root_dir/lib/javascripts/application_lib.js, so I can add lines like require_tree . to recursively search .js files under lib/
But I can't figure out how.

In my application.rb file

```
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib/assets/"
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Interestingly if I put a pile in root_dir/lib/assets/javascripts/greeting.txt, greeting.txt is sourced (localhost:3000/assets/greeting.txt finds the file).
But if I put it in root_dir/lib/assets/stylesheets/greeting.txt, it cant find it. Which means that http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization is wrong.

I even had to add the root/lib/ to my config.assets.paths, it didn't source /lib/ automatically.

Also, I tried making another manifest file under root/lib/javascripts/application.js, but it is not being read as a manifest file and all the recurive files underneath root/lib/javascripts/test/greeting.txt is not being sourced....

How do I recursively source javascript and stylehseets under the lib/ or vendor/ directory ? The only elegant way I can think of is making a new manifest file under lib/javascripts and etc but that hasn't been working...

Thanks!

Comment: This other guy confirms that the rails guide is lying, and has a workaround.

http://climber2002.github.io/blog/2014/08/17/using-index-files-in-rails-4-assets-pipeline/